# Webpack postcss loader, what's its purpose?

Tags: webpack, postcss, postcss-loader

I am trying to find out, what the postcss-loader is good for.

On the github page

https://github.com/postcss/postcss-loader

it says:

**Loader for webpack to process CSS with PostCSS**

I dont't get that: So, PostCSS is a a WP-Loader to process CSS with PostCSS?

IMHO, that's a circular definition.

So what is PostCSS, is it a CSSLoader? Or, since it's called **Post** CSS is it a loader to run after some other CSS-loader?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So, PostCSS is a a WP-Loader to process CSS with PostCSS?

No.

PostCSS-**loader** is a WP-Loader so you can process CSS with PostCSS inside Webpack.

i.e. It loads [PostCSS](https://github.com/postcss/postcss) into Webpack.

> IMHO, that's a circular definition

It isn't because PostCSS and PostCSS-loader are different things.

> So what is PostCSS, is it a CSSLoader?

No. PostCSS is:

> a tool for transforming styles with JS plugins. These plugins can lint your CSS, support variables and mixins, transpile future CSS syntax, inline images, and more.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, it isn't a direct plugin for `PostCSS`, it works inside `Webpack`. if you use `Webpack` in your project for module bundling, then for using `PostCSS` as `CSS Preprocessor` you must use `postcss-loader` and add configs of it.

For example, you can see [THIS REPO](https://gitlab.com/amerllica/react-server-render-example), in `webpack` folder, there is two configuration file for development and production environment, open one of them, no different, and search the `postcss-loader`  word in it, see a complete example of this usage.

Comment: the repo can't be reached via "Access denied"

Comment: @AmirhosseinEbrahimi, this repo is public, but your IP in under USA sanctions, so use a VPN to pass the sanction.

Answer (score 2):

**PostCSS**: use JavaScript plugin to transform CSS.

**PostCSS Loader**: process CSS with PostCSS inside Webpack

Example 1

```
/* Before */
.example {
  display: flex;
}

/* After */
.example {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
}
```

Example 2:

```
/* Before */
:root {
  --green: #00ff00;
}

.example {
  color: var(--green);
}

/* After */
h1 {
  color: #00ff00;
}
```